# How to access data of a data.frame when the name of the data.frame is saved in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm pretty new to R and this question might sound weird.. I have a data.frame with names of other data.frames in the first column:

```
> data  
  tablename avg_size  
1     ttest     5000  
2 testsheet    15000  
5    ttest2    15000  
6    mtcars    13000
```

Then what I would like to do is get the names of the tables (those are data.frames) and run some functions over those data.frames. For example I wanted to get the sum of NAs in each table which was possible using

```
    missing_values <- sum(is.na(eval(as.name(as.vector(data[1])))))
```

My Problem is that 
1) this looks a bit too complicated and I think there may be better solutions? 
2) With other functions I get into trouble, e.g.

```
    infinite_values <- sum(is.infinite(as.numeric(eval(as.name(as.vector(data[1]))))))
```

This doesn't work, inserting "as.numeric" didn't help.

Can someone help?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers so far! I tried both

```
    infinite_values <- sum(is.infinite(as.numeric(eval(as.name(as.vector(data[1]))))))
```

and

```
     obg <- mget( as.character(data[,1]) )
```

but it returns "Error:Values for ´´ttest´´ not found." 
Since this solution seems to work for you, what am i possibly doing wrong?

Comment: I think I detected at least one Problem, "mtcars" is in a different Environment and therefore couldn't be found by mget. now and with the unlist() it seems to work. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use mget and lapply:

```
lapply( mget(as.character(data[,1])), function(x) sum(is.na(x)) )
```

You should not need as.numeric when summing logicals, although using unlist or as.vector may help:

```
lapply( mget(as.character(data[,1])), function(x) sum(is.infinite(unlist(x))) )
```

I put the as.character in there to avoid possible issues with the default interpretation of character input as factor.

Comment: Should be `as.character(data[,1])` instead of `as.character(data[1])`. Also would get all the table as a list first to allow more flexibility in applying different calculations.

Comment: No, actually data[,1] and data[1] are the same for dataframes. I think `mget` (and also `lapply`) return lists, so I don't understand the other part of your suggestion. Oh, wait. Maybe you were suggesting that we assign the results to a "table_list"?

Comment: I was writing an answer and stopped when I saw your post. Anyway, if I put a df like `df <- data.frame(tablename=c("iris", "mtcars"), avg_size=c(5000,13000))`, `as.character(df[,1])` returns `[1] "iris"   "mtcars"`, while `as.character(df[1])` returns `[1] "1:2"`. Can't figure out why too...

Comment: As for the second suggestion, it would look neater to have a list, say `obg <- lapply(as.character(df[,1]), get)` and then sum with `lapply(lapply(obg, is.na), sum)`.

Comment: Ah. df[1] returns that column as a list whereas df[,1] drops the dimension and on gets only a "vector" although possibly a factor variable. The as.character(df[1]) does not properly coerce a factor inside a list to "character" mode. You're right that this will work better along your approach.

Comment: this is easier: `obg <- mget( as.character(df[,1]) )`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using mget, but it gives me "Error:Values for ´´ttest´´ not found." I did use as.character()..

Comment: @mariego without seeing exact code you tried, it's hard to guess what's going on. Consider amending your question with your newest ventures and we'll see what can be done.

Comment: For example I tried "obg <- mget( as.character(data[,1]) )" on my data.frame (see OP) and it returned this error. Same when I use "lapply( mget(as.character(data[,1])), function(x) sum(is.infinite(unlist(x))) )"